# Office-js Excel Sort Worksheet range by multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, excel, sorting, office-js, exceljs

Trying to sort a range of values in excel online using the office.js javascript api by multiple criteria but getting very inconsistent results. I'm attempting to sort based on the value ascending in column 1 but also by font color so each font color is ordered by the value of column 1 in ascending order.

results are very inconsistent. Is there a better way to do this?

```
async function sort(worksheetName) {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(worksheetName);
      console.log("sort worksheet:" + worksheetName);
      let myUsedRange = worksheet.getUsedRange();
      let lastrow = myUsedRange.getLastRow().load(["rowindex", "values"]);
      await context.sync();
      let lastrowindex = lastrow.rowIndex + 1;

      // Add values to the range
      let range = worksheet.getRange("A5:M" + lastrowindex);
      console.log("lastrow index sort:" + lastrowindex);
      // Sort the range
      const sortFields = [
        {
          key: 1,
          sortOn: Excel.SortOn.fontColor,
          ascending: true
        },
        {
          key: 1,
          sortOn: Excel.SortOn.value,
          ascending: true
        },       
      ];
      
      range.sort.apply(sortFields);

      await context.sync();
    });
  }
```

Comment: SortOn.fontcolor appears to be ignored entirely.

Comment: annoyingly this was really simple.. Just needed to add the color  {
              key: 1,
              sortOn: Excel.SortOn.fontColor,
              color:"#000000",
              ascending: true
            },

Answer (score 0):

annoying.. very simple.. just needed to add the color..  {
key: 1,
sortOn: Excel.SortOn.fontColor,
color:"#000000",
ascending: true
},